# Why are the values different of my sub for loops from the main loop when the range of my loops is the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, printing

Hello can someone explain me why would this -

```
size = 10
for x1 in range(-size+1, size):
    for y1 in range(-size+1, size):
        for x2 in range(-size+1, size):
            for y2 in range(-size+1, size):
                print(f'x1: {x1}, y1: {y1}')
                print(f'x2: {x2}, y2: {y2}')
```

give me different values for x1, y1, x2, y2
I tried printing them and the values of them are different. Here is a part of the output.

```
x2: 0, y2: -2
x1: -7, y1: 3
x2: 0, y2: -1
x1: -7, y1: 3
x2: 0, y2: 0
x1: -7, y1: 3
x2: 0, y2: 1
x1: -7, y1: 3
x2: 0, y2: 2
x1: -7, y1: 3
```

If you see the range is the same for all the loops (the main loop and the 3 sub loops)and so I think x1, y1, x2, y2 should all be same. Why are the values different at a few places?

Comment: Pictures of text are really not appreciated here. Can you point to a  few values which seem unexpected? I would expect the four different loop variables to have different values most of the time in a completely predictable fashion and the pictures seem to confirm this expectation.

Comment: @triplee if you see the ranges of all my for loop they are -range(-size+1, size) So I think they should give me the same output.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this is still not clear. It sounds like you expect `x1` and `x2` etc to always contain exactly the same value, but it's unclear why you expect that. They are four different variables and the code works exactly as a reasonable person would expect. If that's not what you expect, again, can you please elucidate on what exactly you expect and how the output you get differs from that? If you want the same value, you need only a single loop; `for x1 in range(-size+1, size): x2 = x1; y1 = x1; y2 = x1`

Comment: In the Tutorial there are supposed to be different values for each iteration. He wants four variables that update independent from each other. This is how nested loops work. For your understanding set size to 4 and remove the two loops for x2 and y2. That should make it clearer to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works exactly as expected. Each loop variable is independent from the others.

Compare:

```
for x1 in (1, 2):
   for x2 in (3, 4):
     for y1 in (5, 6):
       for y2 in (7, 8):
         print(f'x1: {x1} x2: {x2} y1: {y1} y2: {y2}')
```

Would you expect `x2` to take on the values `1` and `2`? Of course not, because it is told to loop over `3` and `4`, and that is indeed what it will do. It is entirely unrelated to `x1`.

Demo: https://ideone.com/F0nQMK

If you wanted all four variables to take on the same value, you should use a single loop:

```
for x1 in range(-size+1, size):
    x2 = x1
    y1 = x1
    y2 = x2
    print(f'x1: {x1} x2: {x2} y1: {y1} y2: {y2}')
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/YOFA3A

Answer (score 1):

Your most inner loop is for the variable y2. This changes for every iteration.  It should become clearer if you replace your print statement with the following

```
print(x1,y1,x2, y2)
```

You will see that the last position changes on every iteration. The others change progressively more slowly.

Therefore given your nested loops it is expected that at least one variable changes in every iteration. This is independent of the range for every variable.